# Optimizing MATLAB code

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

This code takes an extremely long time to run (more than 10 minutes). Is there any way in which I can optimize it so that it finishes in less than one minute?

```
clear all;
for i = 1:1000000
    harmonicsum = 0;
    lhs = 0;
    for j = 1:i
        % compute harmonic sum
        harmonicsum = harmonicsum + 1/j;
        % find sum of factors
        if (mod(i,j)==0)
            lhs = lhs + j;
        end
    end
    %define right hand side (rhs) of Riemann Hypothesis
    rhs = harmonicsum + log(harmonicsum) * exp(harmonicsum);

    if lhs > rhs
        disp('Hypothesis violated')
    end
end
```

Comment: The key is not to ask "what are the factors of N", but "what numbers have `j` as a factor", which is MUCH easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[@b3 has a great vectorization of `rhs`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640010/optimizing-matlab-code/7640648#7640648)

One typo though, needs to use `times` and not `mtimes`:

```
harmonicsum = cumsum(1 ./ (1:1e6));
rhs = harmonicsum + log(harmonicsum) .* exp(harmonicsum);
```

For `lhs`, I propose the following, loosely based on Eratosthenes' Sieve:

```
lhs = 1 + [1:1e6];
lhs(1) = 1;
for iii = 2:numel(lhs)/2
    lhs(2*iii:iii:end) = lhs(2*iii:iii:end) + iii;
end;
```

Execution time is just 2.45 seconds (for this half of the problem).  Total including calculation of `rhs` and `find` is under 3 seconds.

I'm currently running the other version to make sure that the results are equal.

---

EDIT: found a bug with `lhs(1)` and special-cased it (it is a special case, the only natural number where 1 and N aren't distinct factors)

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo. Nice job on the `lhs` calculation. I think all you need is to add 1 to the entire vector.

Comment: For the harmonic sum, do I need to put it within the loop? I don't follow how your code does a harmonic sum for each value of i?

Comment: @icobes: It's the magic of `cumsum`.  Note that `harmonicsum(i) = harmonicsum(i-1) + 1/i`.

Comment: +1 this is seriously fast.. it computes the [sum of divisors](http://oeis.org/A000203) of n, for all n between 1 and 1000000 in under 3 seconds! I tried some of the codes listed on that page, Mathematica version took 15 sec, MuPad version around 100 seconds...

Answer (score 4):

Vectorizing your algorithm where I could reduced the execution time slightly to ~8.5 minutes. Calculate all of the harmonic sums in one statement:

```
harmonicsum = cumsum(1 ./ (1:1e6));
```

You can now calculate the right-hand side in one statement:

```
rhs = harmonicsum + log(harmonicsum) .* exp(harmonicsum);
```

I couldn't vectorize the determination of the factors so this is the fastest way I could come up with to sum them. MATLAB's [FACTOR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/factor.html) command allows you to generate all the prime factors for each iteration. We then compute the unique set of products of all possible combinations using [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) and [NCHOOSEK](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nchoosek.html). This avoids testing each integer as a factor.

```
lhs = zeros(1e6, 1);
for ii = 1:1e6
    primeFactor = factor(ii);
    numFactor = length(primeFactor);
    allFactor = [];
    for jj = 1:numFactor-1
       allFactor = [allFactor; unique(prod(nchoosek(primeFactor, jj), 2))];
    end
    lhs(ii) = sum(allFactor) + 1 + ii;
end
lhs(1) = 1;
```

Find the indices at which the Riemann hypothesis is violated:

```
isViolated = find(lhs > rhs);
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, you get wrong results for `lhs(1)`, `lhs(2)`, `lhs(3)`, and probably all the rest also.

Comment: Ran the original code from the question to find `lhs(1:10)`, mine now matches, yours doesn't, not for a single element :(

Comment: I think the problem (apart from the `ii == 1` case) is that `jj == numFactor` yields `ii` itself, which you're counting separately.  Change the loop to `jj = 1:numFactor` and it should be better.

Comment: That should have said "change the loop to `for jj = 1:numFactor-1`".

Comment: My teacher was able to run this code in less than one minute. Is there any other way to express this code that you can think of?

Comment: @icobes - Look at Ben Voigt's solution. It's much, much faster.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - Fixed the loop count although it is unimportant considering the faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop is executing around 1000000*(1000000+1)/2 = 500000500000 times! No wonder it is slow. Maybe you should try a different approximation approach.

Comment: I don't know how else to test for factors and test each of the 1,000,000 numbers without using a double loop.