# How can I compute all factors of a number in octave (not just prime factors)?

Tags: octave

I am a beginning Octave user and would like to compute all the integer divisors of a number, for example, for the number 120, I would like to get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 24, 30, 40, 60, and 120.

I know octave has the `factor` function, but this only gives the prime factorization. I'd like all the integer divisors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimizing Matlab Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640010/optimizing-matlab-code), which provides ways of both getting all factors of a single number, and all factors of a each number in a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in function for this, so you will need to write one. Since each factor is the product of a subset of the prime factors, you can use a few built-in functions to build up the desired result.

```octave
function rslt = allfactors(N)
%# Return all the integer divisors of the input N
%# If N = 0, return 0
%# If N < 0, return the integer devisors of -N
    if N == 0
        rslt = N;
        return
    end
    if N < 0
        N = -N;
    end

    x = factor(N)'; %# get all the prime factors, turn them into a column vector  '
    rslt = []; %# create an empty vector to hold the result
    for k = 2:(length(x)-1)
        rslt = [rslt ; unique(prod(nchoosek(x,k),2))];
        %# nchoosek(x,k) returns each combination of k prime factors
        %# prod(..., 2) calculates the product of each row
        %# unique(...) pulls out the unique members
        %# rslt = [rslt ...] is a convenient shorthand for appending elements to a vector
    end
    rslt = sort([1 ; unique(x) ; rslt ; N]) %# add in the trivial and prime factors, sort the list
end
```

Comment: This looks like a very slight modification of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640010/optimizing-matlab-code/7640648#7640648, if it is you should give well-deserved credit to [@b3](http://stackoverflow.com/users/14946/b3).

Comment: @Ben - you're right that it's almost identical. I hadn't seen that other question before though. I'm glad to see that I arrived at the same place as b3 on how to simply and efficiently perform this calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I thing this is the one you are looking for.
Hope it could be useful.

### MATLAB / Octave

```
function fact(n);
f = factor(n);  % prime decomposition    
K = dec2bin(0:2^length(f)-1)-'0';   % generate all possible permutations    
F = ones(1,2^length(f));        
for k = 1:size(K)      
   F(k) = prod(f(~K(k,:)));         % and compute products    
end;     
F = unique(F);                      % eliminate duplicates    
printf('There are %i factors for %i.\n',length(F),n);    
disp(F);  
end;'
```

And the following is the Output:

```
>> fact(12)
There are 6 factors for 12.
    1    2    3    4    6   12
>> fact(28)
There are 6 factors for 28.
    1    2    4    7   14   28
>> fact(64)
There are 7 factors for 64.
    1    2    4    8   16   32   64
>>fact(53)
There are 2 factors for 53.
    1   53
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use "divisors":

```
divisors(sym(120))

ans = (sym) [1  2  3  4  5  6  8  10  12  15  20  24  30  40  60  120]  (1×16 matrix)
```